# Using two arrays as an if condition in a nested for loop

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, nested-loops

I'm relatively new to C/C++, and I'm learning about nested for loops and arrays. The question I'm asking is referring to the code below

```
int main(){
    int N, M;
    bool secret = false;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M); //N is the amount of weapon "The Hero" has, while M is the amount for "The Villain"
    int X[N]; // To store the value of "Damage" each weapon has
    int Y[M]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &X[i]); // Inputting the value to each weapon
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        scanf("%d", &Y[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++){
            if(X[i] > Y[j]){  //To check if atleast one weapon of "The Hero" can beat all the weapon of "The Villain" (What i was trying to do anyways)
                secret = true;
            } else{
                secret = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(secret == true){
        printf("The dark secret was true\n");
    } else{
        printf("Secret debunked\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to check if at least one weapon in the X array has a greater value than all of the ones is the Y array(not the sum of Y array). The problem I'm running into is that if I put a the last value in the X array as lower than any of the value in the Y array, it will always return false, and print out out the else statement, because the loop will always got to the last iteration and use that as the statement for the condition.

I was expecting the outcome to be

```
3 5 // The amount of weapons the Hero and Villain has
4 9 2 // The value of each weapon for the Hero
8 4 6 8 3 // The value of each weapon for the Villain

The dark secret was true // The expected output
```

instead, I got

```
Secret Debunked
```

because of the looping to last value in the X array. I tried to stop the if statements using break;, using it in the loop it self, both didn't work as expected. I'm thinking of arranging it first then using specific indexes to compare it. But before trying that I figured to ask here first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are always setting the variable `secret` in each iteration of the inner for loop. So the variable stores its last assigned value.

Rewrite the loops for example the following way

```
for ( int i = 0; !secret && i < N; i++ ){
    int j = 0;

    while ( j < M && X[i] > Y[j] ) j++;

    secret = j == M;
}
```

Comment: Thank a bunch for the help, but could I ask for a more in-depth on how this block of code works?

Comment: @NelsenCookie The inner while loop checks whether X[i] is greater than Y[j]. If the condition will be valid for all elements of the array Y then j after the loop will be equal to M. Otherwise the loop will be interrupted for some j not equal to M.

Comment: If you prefer to know complex logic, you could try to understand the code in the answer but if just solve the problem it can be make in other way like: first find max of Y[], then check if any item of X[i] greater than the max found

Answer (score 0):

breaking the loop once you have found a value (for hero) greater than that for villian will help

```
for (int i = 0; !secret && i < N; i++) { // <= secret == true then exit
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        if (X[i] > Y[j]) {
            secret = true;
            break;  // <= found value, no need to check anymore
        } else{
            secret = false;
        }
    }
}
```